# Initializing an dynamically HtmlGenericControl from a string name

Tags: c#, dynamic, initialization, htmlgenericcontrol

My database currently holds of the names of each Div that need populated on pageload.

Once the Divs are loaded. I retrieve the names of the Divs that need populated, and I then want to populate their inner HTMLs through the c# code behind.

I know that this can normally be done by directly referencing HTML control names like this:

```
    HtmlGenericControl divControl = Div1;

    divControl.InnerHtml = "Div Populated!";
```

My problem is that I want to initialize HtmlGenericControls from Div names stored as strings.

For example:

```
   string DivName = "Div1"

   HtmlGenericControl divControl = DivName;

   divControl.InnerHtml = "Div Populated!";
```

But I get an error when I try this that a string cannot be implicitly converted to an HTML Generic Control.

Does anybody know how I might be able to achieve dynamic initalization of HtmlGenericControls from strings names?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to find control by id.

```
 HtmlGenericControl divControl = parentControlId.FindControl("DivName");
```